Control image with object-posistion CSS
So i have code like this


   img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 1000px;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: left;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  
</head>
<body>
   <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/a-woman-is-shopping-in-a-grocery-store-pf82pJc-4pc" alt="">

</html>



when i resize the screen the image is move to left, but you can see that when screen is below to 500px the girl start disappeared. what i want is when resize the screen the img is focus to that girl so when use a phone the img is on that girl.

Do you require all the girls face to be seen whatever the aspect ratio of the viewport (maybe within some practical limits!).

Specify the focal point of your image using object-position.

The dog’s face is 80% of the way across from the left edge, and 24% of the way down from the top edge, so use object-position: 80% 24%.
Once you have done this, regardless of how the image is sized and cropped, the dog’s face will remain visible.


.i1, .i2 {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 80% 24%;
}

.i1 {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.i2 {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 90vh;
}
<img class="i1" src="http://picsum.photos/id/659/1000">

<img class="i2" src="http://picsum.photos/id/659/1000">



After running this snippet, use the full page link to see the effect properly.

This works pretty well but the face gets cropped on the right side when the viewport is tall e.g. seen on my iPad in portrait mode.
